# Arduino Requirements

Tags: arduino-uno

I have downloaded the arduino Environment on my windows XP and also set the driver properly.
I discovered the arduino uno device on the device manager display list disappeared whenever I unplugged the arduino UNO. I want to know if there are extra things needed to set up the device as none of my sketches has ever gotten flashed to the board.
Someone told me I need Java (Compiler and Runtime) to use arduino is this true?
I only have JVR

Comment: Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWY_Is0L7fE

Comment: or Watch this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HqXAmV_Ock

Comment: I have watched the two movies Sir but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: This is exactly what I get 'Arduino: 1.0.6 (Windows XP),  Board: "Arduino Uno" C:\New Folder\New\arduino-1.0.6\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avr-objcopy: 'Blink.cop.elf' : No such file

Comment: Are you getting an error when you program the board? What's wrong, exactly? P.S. it should disappear from device manager when it is unplugged; that is normal behavior.